# Laravel Using AJAX to pass Javascript variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass a variable from my javascript code to the server side PHP code. I know this must be done via an ajax, But unfortunately I do not receive the value in the PHP variable in blade view.

form : url = facture=20

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=> 'admin/facture=20', 'method'=>'post',   'name'=>'pushds')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('ms_id', $fact->id) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('mstid', $fact->b_id, array('id' => 'mstid')) !!}     
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

jquery :

```
$('form[name="pushds"]').on('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

  var mstid = $('#mstid').val();
  var ms_id = $('#ms_id').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'facture=20',            
            data: {mstid: $('#mstid').val(), ms_id : $('#ms_id').val()},
            success: function( data ) {
......
},
```

the current page url : facture=20

the variable php in blade view

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST["mstid "])) {
echo $_POST['mstid ']; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you look in the console and see the ajax request and the data being sent with it to make sure the data is actually being passed?  Also look in the response and make sure it's actually being echoed.

Comment: if you means console.log xhr, there is the data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In form** (*Add id field to from*)

```
{!! Form::hidden('ms_id', $fact->id, array('id' => 'ms_id')) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('mstid', $fact->b_id, array('id' => 'mstid')) !!}
```

**In AJAX**

```
var mstid = $('#mstid').val(); # Calling through respective ID
var ms_id = $('#ms_id').val(); # Calling through respective ID

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'facture=20',            
    data: {mstid: mstid , ms_id : ms_id }, # passing variables 
    success: function( data ) {
```

---

> **Make sure your from submit reaches the AJAX code. You can test it by using `alert()` inside AJAX function ..**

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to pass javascript value to server side using ajax:

Method 1:

Change your ajax code to:

From:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'facture=20',            
            data: {mstid: $('#mstid').val(), ms_id : $('#ms_id').val()},
            success: function( data ) {
......
},
```

To:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'facture=20',            
            data: {mstid: $('input[name=mstid]').val(), ms_id : $('input[name=ms_id]').val()},
            success: function( data ) {
......
},
```

And on server side you can get it as :

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["mstid "]) && $_POST["mstid "] != "") {
echo $_POST['mstid ']; 
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Even if I fixed the variable i get nothing : data: {mstid: '7', ms_id : '13'},

Comment: Error message : Undefined index: mstid

Comment: @nabil please open the console and see the post data. is it going to server? Is there any error in console?

Comment: @nabil check if (isset($_POST["mstid"])  &&  $_POST["mstid"] != "") { echo $_POST['mstid ']; }    or check it by  if ( $_POST["mstid"] != "" ) { echo $_POST['mstid ']; } there was something wrong

Comment: always the same thing!